# jQuery code only works on page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple jQuery script that changes a value pulled dynamically like so:

```
(function($) {

    $(window).load(function () {
        $(function(){
            var inNum = parseFloat($(".value").text().match(/[\d\.\d]+/i)).toFixed(2);
            $('span.value').text(inNum);
        });
    });
}(jQuery));
```

However the script only works when the page is refreshed. I have tried using

```
$(document.body).ready(function() {
```

but still no luck. The script needs to run once two other scripts have completed which I think could be causing the problem, but a refresh always fixes the issue. Are there any other reasons as to why this is happening? Can I set the script to load after everything else has loaded other than using .load?

Comment: is `$(".value")` being populated dynamically?

Comment: Remove the outer wrapping `$(window).load(function () { ... });`. You want to bind to the `DOMContentLoaded` event (document ready) before it fires. I'm guessing the wrapping may be causing the `$(function() { ... });` document ready wrapper shorthand to bind after the `DOMContentLoaded` event has already fired, preventing your code from executing.

Comment: can you add the code for the other two scripts which are loading the data? Just curious to know at what point are these scripts being loaded

Comment: Thanks for the prompt replies. It was only until I read @Nikitesh Kolpe's comment that I took a look at the other script and realised that the code needed to be loaded within an ajax function as it was being ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function isn't working probably because some resource (script, css or image) still loading, so the `load` event is only fired when you hit refresh which causes all resources to stop loading. It causes the `load` event to be fired in the actual page.

You can just use:

```
(function($) {
    $(function(){
        var inNum = parseFloat($(".value").text().match(/[\d\.\d]+/i)).toFixed(2);
        $('span.value').text(inNum);
    });
}(jQuery));
```

The `jQuery` variable still be mapped to `$` inside your function and your script will be executed when the DOM is ready (even if some resource still loading).

Comment: You are right, the code needed to be loaded within an ajax function as it was being ignored.

Comment: Is there a vanilla javascript equivalent to this?

Comment: Yes, the DOMContentLoaded event. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var inNum = parseFloat($(".value").text().match(/[\d\.\d]+/i)).toFixed(2);
    $('span.value').text(inNum);
});
```

It will execute the code right away when the DOM is loaded.

Comment: The OP has this. `$(function () { ... });` is shorthand for `$(document).ready`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put your code in a function:

```
 function TestCall()
{
  var inNum = parseFloat($(".value").text().match(/[\d\.\d]+/i)).toFixed(2);
  $('span.value').text(inNum);
}
```

And call this function on window.onload:

```
  window.onload=TestCall;
```

This should work in your case.

Answer (score 1):

I trust my answer comes very late but this goes to those still having this problem. After spending 2 days trying all possible solutions posted on the Internet in vain, the only thing that helped was going the old fashion way

I added the onclick clause on the button.

```
<a href="#" id="createAccbtn" onclick="handle_creatAccbtn_function()" ....
```

I know this might not be the best solution but it worked. Got a client off my back and can be looking  for better solution without someone breathing down my neck.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but solved it with this inside the $(document).ready to reload the page only once.

```
if(!window.location.hash) {
        window.location = window.location + '#loaded';
        window.location.reload();
    }else{
      //Init stuff here
    }
```

I prefer this solution above adding a plugin and messing up code everywhere. Avoid using location reload(true); 'true' means it will empty the cache and causes double download traffic.